# .htaccess - how to load css files when adding a folder virtual through .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here are .htaccess codes I took from other sites which are working perfect.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/add productadd.php [L]
```

last line virtually creates "products" folder which is fine but problem is mysite.com/products/add can not load css, icon files since they are in root directory (not in virtual folder).

btw, being newbie I can't understand all these codes. all tutorials provide direct solutions instead of telling what ^([^.]+)$ do and how to change as per requirement.

Comment: for the time being i am using php to fix this issue but still need proper solution in .htaccess if possible.